# Simulate ring (algebra) in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, algebra

I'm creating small profile viewer and I want to simulate ring in SQL. How it works? For simple:
I have 5 users on my table. When I get one from middle to my experiment (like user number 2,3,4) next and previous user is CURRENT_USER_ID +- 1. But when I choose user number 1 or 5 it's not that simply like before. So if I have some tool like algebra ring it's easy. Can I simulate it?

Oh, I'm using MySQL.

Comment: you can work with MAX and MIN if the current ID is MAX(ID) then the next ID is MIN(ID), if the current ID is MIN(ID) then the previous ID is MAX(ID)

Comment: if you can provide which sql you are working with (sql server, mysql, oracle) I can provide you with a more detailed answer

Comment: I forgot about it, I'm using MySQL :)

Comment: dand I started figuring it out in sql server, back to the drawing board :D

Comment: I just realised I have absolutely now idea how to create a stored procedure in mysql :P

Comment: Send it to me if you can :)

Comment: I already tossed it and working on mysql version (it wasn't finished anyways)

Comment: I think I got what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:
[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c271/17)

```
set @curr_user = 1;
set @maxid = (select max(u1.id) maxid from users u1);
set @minid = (select min(u2.id) minid from users u2);
set @next_user = (if(@curr_user = @maxid
                           ,@minid
                           ,@curr_user +1));
set @prev_user = (if(@curr_user = @minid
                           ,@maxid
                           ,@curr_user - 1));

SELECT t1.name as prevuser, t2.name as curruser, t3.name as nextuser
FROM users t1
join users t2
on 1=1
JOIN users t3
on 1=1
WHERE t1.id = @prev_user
AND t2.id = @curr_user
and t3.id = @next_user
```

EDIT: I made a slight adjustment so it would work even if there are missing id's, let's say you have user 1,3,4,5,7 this would get user 4,5,7 if current is 5 [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2307/3)

```
set @curr_user = 3;
set @maxid = (select max(u1.id) maxid from users u1);
set @minid = (select min(u2.id) minid from users u2);
set @nextid = (select min(id) from users where id > @curr_user );
set @previd = (select max(id) from users where id < @curr_user );
set @next_user = (if(@curr_user = @maxid
                           ,@minid
                           ,@nextid));
set @prev_user = (if(@curr_user = @minid
                           ,@maxid
                           ,@previd));

SELECT t1.name as prevuser, t2.name as curruser, t3.name as nextuser
FROM users t1
join users t2
on 1=1
JOIN users t3
on 1=1
WHERE t1.id = @prev_user
AND t2.id = @curr_user
and t3.id = @next_user
```

Comment: Thanks bro :) I own you one :D

Comment: @stachu you might run into issues when you have missing id's though, so watch out for those (let's say you have id 3 and 5 but no 4 this code won't work), you won't even get a null value in that case, you will just get no result